# XPath Query Help Syntax

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, xpath

I am having some difficulty with an xPath expression.

Context:  I am using an XML document to store queries / stored procedure names in an ASP application.  I use a utility function to load the xmldocument (if it isn't previously loaded) and I am attempting to select the node set from the document that matches an Id element.  Here is my Xml document:

```
<Queries>
  <Id>USER001
    <Sql>spUsers_GetUserByUserName</Sql>
  </Id >
  <Id <USER002
    <Sql>spUsers_GetUserByEmail</Sql>
</Queries>
```

Here is the code (I am using VB.NET)

```
Module Utility

private sqlXml as xmldocument

'....other stuff.....


Public Function GetSql(queryId as string) as string

dim qry as string
dim node as XmlNode

if sqlXml is nothing then
   sqlXml = new xmldocument
   sqlXml.Load (..path)
end if 

qry = "//Id['" & queryId  & "']"    'xPath to select the Id node = to paramter passed

node = sqlxml.SelectSingleNode(qry) 'set node <Id><Sql></Sql></Id>

return node.SelectSingleNode("//Sql").InnerText 'Return the Sql element value from the Id

End Function
```

The Problem:

the node variable only returns the first  element.  I have verified the that the `qry` string that is used to `SelectSingleNode` IS the correct Id value (i.e. USER002) - however the node is getting loaded with the USER001 element.  It is obviously the xPath expression that is messed up.  What do I need to tweak on the xPath expression so that I can return the correct `<Id>` element and corresponding child `<Sql>` element.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @jbd: The XML sample is useless. Please, do post a better example and use the **`{}`** button.

Comment: @jbd: the XML is not well formed.

Answer (score 0):

Google XML COOKTOP and install it. It's a  great little freeware app for trying out XPATH and XSLT expressions on XML data files and seeing the results.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to to construct an expression like `//Id['USER002']`. That will select all the E elements for which the effective boolean value of 'USER002' is true - which is all of them. It's not clear what you intended because your XML sample is a mess, but it should be something like `//Id[@id='USER002']`

Also, you really shouldn't be constructing XPath expressions by string concatenation. It leaves you prone to injection attacks and to accidental misfunctioning when someone supplies a string containing quotes. It's also inefficient. Construct a string containing a variable reference $param, and set the parameter from the API. (Don't know how to do that in VB, I'm afraid).

Comment: I apologize for the screwed up XML.  The actual document is well formed.  Michael - that is indeed what I am trying to do. The net effect is I am trying to get to the SQL tag that is a child of the Id tag with a value matching the parameter supplied.  The example I used was a value supplied of "USER002"; if that is supplied I would expect to return the Sql inner text with a value of spUsers_GetUserByEmail.  That isn't happening - I am getting the spUsers_GetUserByUsername.  I will try your suggestion "//Id[@Id='" & queryId & "']".  I also look into the technique you specified.  Thanks.